# Why are these peak intensities in Young's experiment the same?

Tags: interference, double-slit-experiment, diffraction

I took the following image from the book Sears and Zemansky's University Physics with Modern Physics by Young and Freedman.
[image]

I don't understand why the relation $d = 4a$ makes the peak intensities in images (a) and (b) equal.

Comment: If the intensity of light measured by unit of surface of the plane on which the slits are cut were the same in case (a) and case (c), $I_0$ at the center of (c) would be exactly four times the one at the center  of (a). Indeed, $E$ would be doubled and thus $I$ quadrupled..

Comment: @Alfred yes, that was my first thought. But I suspected that I was missing something because the authors specially mention $d=4a$ and none of those arguments make use of this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the diagrams here only demonstrate *relative intensity* graphs. This means $I_{0}$ in (a) is not the same as $I_{0}$ in (b). The only thing they're interested in here is the shape of the intensity function, the location of the peaks/valleys, and the widths of the graphs.

The information $d = 4a$ here is only relevant to the angular widths of the two graphs in (a) and (b), and it is only relevant to how you obtain graph (c) by multiplying function (a) by function (b).

If I'm not mistaken, they don't ever go into the detail of how to calculate absolute intensity (which is possible but intro physics books leave it out because it is a very difficult topic), so there's not as much meaning to $I_{0}$ as you think there is.

Comment: In this book it is explained how to get $I_0$ from the electric field amplitude, in a previous chapter. It is for that reason and the fact that they specially define $d = 4a$ (which wouldn't be needed at all for a qualitative explanation) that I suspect I am missing something.

Comment: @Javi But do they explain how to get the electric field amplitude in a single slit / double slit? Yes, I am aware there's a relationship between $E$ and $I$, but that's not the same thing as calculating the exact value of $I_{0}$. They want you to focus on the widths of the graphs, not the heights. They specifically define $d=4a$ because it produces 7 humps in the middle envelope spot and 3 humps in the two side envelope spots in (c).

Comment: Oh right, no. They only write the relationship between $I$ and $E$. Thanks for clarifying about the $d=4a$ thing.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is some misunderstanding. Images (a), (b) and (c) are not drawn for the same intensity of light being shone on the slits. $I_0$ is just an arbitrary normalisation.

What these three images are meant to explain is the following.
Unless a single slit is narrow enough (width $a$ is supposed small) you won't have a wide enough diffraction pattern. Image (a) shows a diffusion pattern with a single slit, and just calls $I_0$ the intensity at the center, for some   intensity of light arriving on the slit.

If the single slit was much much narrower, you'd have a much wider pattern. Of course, since *less* light can get through a narrower slit and the light is diffracted on a wider area, you'd have even less light on the central area of the screen. Having the same $I_0$ would mean a much, much higher intensity incoming to the slit. This is not represented here, but it would be a horizontal line at some amplitude. Why not again $I_0$ ? One does not say the incoming intensity is the same ! The horizontal does not mean it goes to infinity, just much wider than on (a).

With tow very narrow slits you get pattern (b). It does **not** extend to infinity, but the idea is again that it extends much wider than (a). Again it is for a different intensity, just adjusted for the same $I_0$  at the center.

Finally two slits, distance 4$a$, but with width $a$. The overall shape is the same as (a). The interference pattern is the same as (b). The combined effect is (c) : an interference pattern limited under an envelope shaped like (a). But all the intensities for the incoming illumination are different for the same $I_0$.